# BlockingSwitchOutError in debugger after upgrading to PyCharm 2016.2

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

After upgrading from PyCharm 2016.1.4 to 2016.2, when running the debugger and setting any breakpoint, PyCharm halts in various places where I have no breakpoint set, and logs this to stderr:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/pycharm/debug-eggs/pycharm-debug.egg/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 539, in trace_dispatch
    self.do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg)
  File "/usr/local/pycharm/debug-eggs/pycharm-debug.egg/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 71, in do_wait_suspend
    self._args[0].do_wait_suspend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/pycharm/debug-eggs/pycharm-debug.egg/pydevd.py", line 714, in do_wait_suspend
    time.sleep(0.01)
  File "/home/jaza/mypyapp/mypyfile.py", line 999, in mypyfunc
    gevent.sleep(seconds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 194, in sleep
    hub.wait(loop.timer(seconds, ref=ref))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 630, in wait
    result = waiter.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 878, in get
    return self.hub.switch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 608, in switch
    switch_out()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 612, in switch_out
    raise BlockingSwitchOutError('Impossible to call blocking function in the event loop callback')
BlockingSwitchOutError: Impossible to call blocking function in the event loop callback
```

OS: Linux Mint 17.3 (i.e. almost identical to Ubuntu 14.04). Using latest gevent (1.1.2).

If I open my old PyCharm (i.e. 2016.1.4), and do the same thing - i.e. start the debugger, set a breakpoint, run my app - I don't get these errors, and PyCharm doesn't halt anywhere in the code except at my breakpoint.

I also tried just "downgrading" the debugger, by renaming the `debug-eggs` directory and replacing it with a symlink to the old `debug-eggs` path, and then running the rest of PyCharm on the latest version. This didn't fix the problem, i.e. it still resulted in BlockingSwitchOutError being raised numerous times.

Seems likely that this is a bug in PyCharm 2016.2. I've submitted a bug report to JetBrains for this, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20183 . But posting here on SO as well, in case anyone sees a problem with the code in my app (the use of `gevent.sleep(seconds)` ?), meaning that the code happened to work before, but was going to break sooner or later.

Comment: I have the exactly same error. PyCharm 2016.1.4 works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution posted by Elizaveta Shashkova on the PyCharm issue tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20183 worked for me:

> The new feature has appeared in PyCharm: breakpoint thread suspend policy. You should go Run | View breakpoints, select the breakpoint and change its threads suspend policy: "Thread" or "All". Also you can set the default policy for all your breakpoints.

After changing suspend policy from "All" to "Thread", debugger is no longer breaking outside of my breakpoints nor throwing `BlockingSwitchOutError`.

And, re:

> Also do you have the setting "gevent compatible" turned on? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/python-debugger.html

No, I don't have this turned on, and I fixed my issue without turning it on. But will try turning it on if I have similar issues in future.